# DRCSIM: SDF bug prevents roslaunch from working

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The version of Gazebo/drcsim loaded using

```
sudo apt-get install drcsim
```

works when invoked with just

```
gazebo
```

but has the following fatal errors when invoked
as

```
roslaunch atlas_utils atlas.launch
```

```
Error [SDF.cc:993] Unable to find value for key[link_name]
Error [SDF.cc:993] Unable to find value for key[link_name]
Exception [Joint.cc:125] Couldn't Find Parent Link[]
Error [Model.cc:153] LoadJoint Failed
```

These messages are repeated about 28 times.
This message is at the end:

```
Error [SDF.cc:761] Missing element description for [link_name]
[gazebo-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/cga/.ros/log/e01679e8-a55e-11e2-9de5-d4bed9fd5ae1/gazebo-2*.log
```

Trying to invoke our copy of the atlas urdf (the one that works with drcsim-nightly installed) with

```
gazebo world
```

has the same problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2387/drcsim:-sdf-bug-prevents-roslaunch-from-working./) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-04-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on 2013-04-15**:
Same problem here...
Just before the error there are several warnings about SDF conversion. Not sure if it is related.
Regards,
LR

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-04-15**:
Same here!   https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/198/nightly-build-busted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks for the report.  A fix is being prepared in [gazebo pull request #451](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/451), to be included in a forthcoming gazebo 1.6.3 release.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1